# Extract text between brackets using Zapier

Tags: extract, brackets, zapier

I’m trying to extract the text between brackets on a feed into Zapier.

The feed from the api reads “tickets purchased using discount code (x123456) blah blah”

I want the random code that shows in the brackets. So I can send it to another application.

The code varies in length and format.

Comment: Give us some code you have tried so we can help

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . Put more details of the issue that you are facing. Include the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved I changed the ( to AAAAA and ) to BBBBB then used the strip function to drop AAAAA and prior and BBBB and